# Log output of multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, logging, concurrency, multiprocessing

Is there a way to log the stdout output from a given `Process` when using the `multiprocessing.Process` class in python?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The easiest way might be to just override `sys.stdout`.  Slightly modifying an example from [the multiprocessing manual](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import sys

def info(title):
    print title
    print 'module name:', __name__
    print 'parent process:', os.getppid()
    print 'process id:', os.getpid()

def f(name):
    sys.stdout = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "w")
    info('function f')
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    q = Process(target=f, args=('fred',))
    q.start()
    p.join()
    q.join()
```

And running it:

```
$ ls
m.py
$ python m.py
$ ls
27493.out  27494.out  m.py
$ cat 27493.out 
function f
module name: __main__
parent process: 27492
process id: 27493
hello bob
$ cat 27494.out 
function f
module name: __main__
parent process: 27492
process id: 27494
hello fred
```

Answer (score 24):

There are only two things I would add to @Mark Rushakoff answer. When debugging, I found it really useful to change the `buffering` parameter of my `open()` calls to 0.

```
sys.stdout = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "a", buffering=0)
```

Otherwise, **madness**, because when `tail -f`ing the output file the results can be verrry intermittent. `buffering=0` for `tail -f`ing great.

And for completeness, do yourself a favor and redirect `sys.stderr` as well.

```
sys.stderr = open(str(os.getpid()) + "_error.out", "a", buffering=0)
```

Also, for convenience you might dump that into a separate process class if you wish,

```
class MyProc(Process):
    def run(self):
        # Define the logging in run(), MyProc's entry function when it is .start()-ed 
        #     p = MyProc()
        #     p.start()
        self.initialize_logging()

        print 'Now output is captured.'

        # Now do stuff...

    def initialize_logging(self):
        sys.stdout = open(str(os.getpid()) + ".out", "a", buffering=0)
        sys.stderr = open(str(os.getpid()) + "_error.out", "a", buffering=0)

        print 'stdout initialized'
```

[Heres a corresponding gist](https://gist.github.com/namoopsoo/104dd7c568df17255bb5)

Comment: I got a ValueError when trying this in python 3.6 since buffering=0 is only allowed for binary mode. But you can fix it by removing the buffering=0 from the monkey patching of sys.stdout/stderr and adding flush=True to your print statements. I.e. print("Stdout initialized", flush=True). It works like a charm.

Comment: Realised that the opened files are not being closed. Is this going to be a problem?

Answer (score 14):

You can set `sys.stdout = Logger()` where `Logger` is a class whose `write` method (immediately, or accumulating until a `\n` is detected) calls `logging.info` (or any other way you want to log). [An example of this in action.](https://github.com/jdloft/multiprocess-logging/blob/master/main.py)

I'm not sure what you mean by "a given" process (who's given it, what distinguishes it from all others...?), but if you mean you know what process you want to single out that way at the time you instantiate it, then you could wrap its `target` function (and that only) -- or the `run` method you're overriding in a `Process` subclass -- into a wrapper that performs this sys.stdout "redirection" -- and leave other processes alone.

Maybe if you nail down the specs a bit I can help in more detail...?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simple and straightforward way for capturing stdout for  [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.Process) and [io.TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io%20textiowrapper#io.TextIOWrapper):

```
import app
import io
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process


def run_app(some_param):
    out_file = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb', 0)
    sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(out_file, write_through=True)
    app.run()

app_process = Process(target=run_app, args=('some_param',))
app_process.start()
# Use app_process.termninate() for python <= 3.7.
app_process.kill()
```

Comment: This doesnt allow a change of redirection as the app is running

Answer (score 3):

The log_to_stderr() function is the simplest solution.

From [PYMOTW](https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/basics.html):

> multiprocessing has a convenient module-level function to enable logging called log_to_stderr(). It sets up a logger object using logging and adds a handler so that log messages are sent to the standard error channel. By default, the logging level is set to NOTSET so no messages are produced. Pass a different level to initialize the logger to the level of detail desired.

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Process, log_to_stderr

print("Running main script...")

def my_process(my_var):
    print(f"Running my_process with {my_var}...")

# Initialize logging for multiprocessing.
log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)

# Start the process.
my_var = 100;
process = Process(target=my_process, args=(my_var,))
process.start()
process.kill()
```

This code will output both print() statements to stderr.

Comment: Neat, looks cleaner to me that overwriting `stdout`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Except from the accepted answer, if your subprocess may create subprocess too, to capture the output of grandchild process, you can try:

```
dst = open("stdout.log", "a")
dst_fd = dst.fileno()
stdout_fd = sys.stdout.fileno()
os.close(stdout_fd)
os.dup2(dst_fd, stdout_fd)
```