# bash fetch stdout/stderr of python multiprocessing Process

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have some sort of multi-agent system running locally implemented in Python using ZeroMQ. The master is started as the main thread (`python Admin.py`) and this one starts the worker agents as `multiprocessing.Process` sub-processes.

Both the Admin.py and the workers write output using simple `print` commands. Now I try to fetch *all* output that I see on my console: `$ python Admin.py > file.txt`. But this statement only fetches the output written by the Admin.py. I tried various redirects such as piping sterr into stdout and than fetches stdout (`1>&2 > file.txt`) but without any result. This question has been asked in various forms on Satckoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714868/python-multiprocessing-how-can-i-reliably-redirect-stdout-from-a-child-process) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501651/log-output-of-multiprocessing-process)) and the answers seem to involve quite some additional python coding. Is there a Bash solution to this issue? I see all output on my console, so why can't Bash redirect it to a file?

Comment: Isn't it `2>&1 > file.txt` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta or better yet `> file.out 2>&1`. Order matters in redirections. Your example 1) redirects stderr to the same place stdout is currently going, then 2) redirects stdout (but not stderr) to go someplace else...