# Log output of multiprocessing when processes call external programs

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, external

I'd like to log the output of several processes I start with multiprocessing. My question is related to  [Log output of multiprocessing.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501651/log-output-of-multiprocessing-process) .

However, the difficulty is, that I'm using some library that calls external programs which output to `stdout`. Is there a way of capturing the output of these external programs called within python session opened by `multiprocessor` without altering the code of that library that calls these programs?

Edit:
The processes of python started by multiprocessing seem to have some more subprocesses I guess that's why some of the output is still printed to `stdout`.
[image: I get output files for PIDs 4491, 4490, and 4489]
I get output files for PIDs 4491, 4490, and 4489

Comment: But aren't these all child processes inheriting your parent processes stdout channel? How did your attempt fail, any error traces that could give us hints? As I understand the referenced page, the trick offered there is to redfine sys.stdout

Comment: That's the question. Apparently not, otherwise I wouldn't see all the output of these subprocesses in `stdout` whereass all python output is succesfully written to these output files

Comment: So, no error trace, no complaints, just displaying a bunch of stuff in stdout, which is of course screwed up to to the parallel workers. I could redirect `stdout/err` to `/dev/null` but then I'd loose information I'd actually like to capture

Comment: Off console for now, I am, will try later again.