# Python : Print output of each thread on different file

Tags: python

I want to print the output of each thread on different files. 
This is my code for threads :-

```
 def __init__(self, command):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.command = command


def run(self):
        call(self.command) 

def get_devices():

       command_res = 'adb devices'
       results = os.popen(command_res, "r")
       command_result = ''
       while 1:
          line = results.readline()
          if not line: break
          command_result += line
       devices = command_result.partition('\n')[2].replace('n','').split('\tdevice')
       return [device for device in devices if len(device) > 2]

for device_id in device_ids :
    threads.append(Universal([sys.argv[1], device_id]))

for thread in threads:
    try:
        thread.start();
    except:
        print("Error: unable to start thread")

for thread in threads:
    thread.join();
```

Here device_ids is the list of my devices attached. Each device runs on separate thread. 
Is there a solution to do this in Python. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

use logger for logging or write to file

1. Create a function to get new logger with new file handler. At the

   ```
   import logging
   from threading import Thread
   import sys
   import subprocess

   device_ids = ["d1","d2","d3"]
   threads = []
   def get_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):

       handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)        
       logger = logging.getLogger(name)
       logger.setLevel(level)
       logger.addHandler(handler)

       return logger


   class Universal(Thread):
       def __init__(self, command,device_id,logger):
           Thread.__init__(self)
           self.command = command
           self.logger = logger
           self.logger.info("thread instance init" + str(device_id))

       def run(self):
           self.logger.info("thread started" + str(device_id))
           subprocess.call(self.command) 


   for device_id in device_ids :
       name = str(device_id) 
       f_name = str(device_id) + str(".log")
       log = get_logger(name,f_name)
       threads.append(Universal(sys.argv[1], device_id,log))

   for thread in threads:
       try:
           thread.start();
       except:
           print("Error: unable to start thread")

   for thread in threads:
       thread.join();
   ```

Save it module a.py and run it with command

```
  python a.py ls
```

**Output**

```
 Public  Videos  d1.log  Desktop github Music Templates d2.log Doccuments gitlab Pictures  d3.log  Downloads torch

 Public  Videos  d1.log  Desktop github Music Templates d2.log Doccuments gitlab Pictures  d3.log  Downloads torch

 Public  Videos  d1.log  Desktop github Music Templates d2.log Doccuments gitlab Pictures  d3.log  Downloads torch
```

Comment: I get this error AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'info'

Comment: When i run the script what should i pass as arguments? As i get the device id later in script and how about logger

Comment: Actually i have other scripts in bash called in runtime which should run by this python script. When i run your code it do give me some thread specific files but i am not able to pass my bass scripts as arguments

Comment: I get this error...... Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 804, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "./Universals.py", line 46, in run
    call(self.command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @NehaAgarwal this error due to the path that you provide is incorrect. run python programme with full path like  'python universals.py /home/...path to bash'

Comment: I am already in my scripts directory i run command something like [nagarwal@bernache testScripts]$ python ./Universals.py ./testAgreement.sh

Comment: @NehaAgarwal as I already said that run it with full classified path of bash

Answer (score 0):

The `print` call is not thread-safe, so you can either use the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module and register a `FileHandler` for each thread, or use multiprocessing instead of threading, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501651/log-output-of-multiprocessing-process).