# Capturing stdout/stderr and function return value in a threaded context

Tags: python, multithreading, function, return, stdout

I need to be able to capture the return value of a function and its `stdout`/`stderr` in a threaded context.  Currently, I'm evaluating a number of subclasses (`my_class_foo`, `my_class_bar`) based on this base class (`my_base_class`) by invoking the `is_true` method in each subclass.

I'd like to be able to capture both the return value from each `is_true` as well as the `stdout`/`stderr`.  The current solution below works in a non-threaded or non-multiprocess context.  However, it relies on redirecting the `stdout`/`stderr` which obviously won't work if I'm evaluating more than one of these subclasses in parallel.

I've looked at the `concurrent.futures` and `multiprocess` and `subprocess` packages and can't figure out a solution.

I'm trying to avoid using loggers so that users can just rely on printing to `stdout` instead of using an explicit method.

I would like to execute the `is_true` methods from `my_class_foo` and `my_class_bar` and in parallel and be able to capture the `stdout` messages with each class' return value.

```
class my_class_foo(my_base_class):
    def is_true(self):
        print('foo')
        return True


class my_class_bar(my_base_class):
    def is_true(self):
        print('bar')
        return False


class my_base_class(object):

    def is_true(self):
        Raise NotImplementedError

    def evaluate_node_is_true(self):
        with Capturing() as is_true_stdout:
            node_is_true = self.is_true()
            self.output = ''.join(is_true_stdout)


class Capturing(list):
    """
    Context manager for capturing the stdout of the is_true() function call
    """
    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        self._stderr = sys.stderr
        sys.stdout = self._stringio_out = io.StringIO()
        sys.stderr = self._stringio_err = io.StringIO()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.extend(self._stringio_out.getvalue().splitlines())
        self.extend(self._stringio_err.getvalue().splitlines())
        del self._stringio_out
        del self._stringio_err
        sys.stdout = self._stdout
        sys.stderr = self._stderr
```

Comment: Does this have to work with threads, or can it work only with processes? Because the latter is a whole lot easier.

Comment: Also: "I've looked at the concurrent.futures and multiprocess and subprocess packages…" What did you try? Firing off a `subprocess.run` on `sys.executable` with captured stdio is dead simple, and I don't see why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: By the way, there's been some talk of making `stdout` and friends wrappable in a PEP 567 contextvar once they're tied together properly with subinterpreters. Don't hold your breath—the earliest it could plausibly happen is 3.9, even if they decide to do it—but it would obviously make this problem a lot easier.

Comment: If I can get this to work with processes, then I'll be satisfied.  The problem with processes is that I don't know how to get the return value on the sys.executable in your answer below.  Is there a way to do that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, a subprocess can't return anything except an 8-bit integer, so you'll need to find some other way to pass it—a special final line in stdout, or a pipe that you pass down as an extra fd, etc.

Comment: Given that the return value on my function is just a bool, I could override the return code with my own setting, i.e. true = 100 and false = 101.  This way I could get stdout/stderr and the return value of the sys.executable.  Would I be opening myself up to any other issues if I tried this when using subprocess?

Comment: Actually, if the return value is a bool, you might want to use `0` for either true (or whichever of true/false best matches "success", if it's more about success than truth) and 1 for false (or maybe some other value between 2 and 127 for whichever one best matches "failure").

Comment: That's what I'll do.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably `subprocess`. Of course this won't work if you want to share any data with the children. And it will require writing a simple separate driver script for the subprocess instead of relying on the same script as the main program. But if it works, it's as simple as this:

```
res = subprocess.run([sys.executable, driver_script_name],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And then you've got `res.stdout` and `res.stderr` to read from.

To do multiple children concurrently, the simplest solution is to fire off a thread for each `subprocess.run`. If you want a pool of only, say, 8 at a time, use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead.

The biggest problem with `subprocess` for a problem like yours is that you want stdout, and stderr, and a return value. Processes give you stdout, stderr, and a return *code*, but that code is just an 8-bit number.

In your case (based on your comments), the return value is actually a bool, so that may be fine. There's a quasi-standard for Unix command-line tools that do boolean things to return `0` for true and `1` for false—as with the `true` and `false` tools.

This is backward from what you'd probably expect, but it fits in with the more general quasi-standard that 0 means success, 1 means general error, 2 means parameter error, 3-127 are tool-specific errors, and 128-255 are not used because you sometimes lose the last bit if killed by a signal. If you (or your users) might ever want to test your sub-programs from the shell, go with 0 for true.

---

You can also do this with `multiprocessing`, but it's a bit trickier. You can create the pipes manually and dup them over stdio, but that's hard to get right. Worse, I don't think the way to do it is documented, so you'll have to dig into the source for `multiprocessing` to do it.

---

In fact, at least if you're on *nix, it might be easier to manually `fork` in that case. Sure, it's low-level, and there's lots of room for error—but then (assuming you know Unix `fork` well enough) you know exactly what to do and where.

---

A simpler option for `multiprocessing` is to do what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501651/log-output-of-multiprocessing-process) demonstrates and just have each child redirect its stdout to a file, which the parent can then read later.

---

One option that will work even for threads is to replace `sys.stdout` with a custom file-like object that appends to a thread-specific buffer. You could use thread-local data and then copy it back at the end, but it might be simpler to just use a dict keyed by thread id. Something like this:

```
class ThreadedStdWriter(io.RawIOBase):
    ThreadedStdWriter.buffers = {}
    def __init__(self):
        ThreadedStdWriter.buffers[threading.get_ident()] = []
    def write(self, b):
        ThreadedStdWriter.buffers.append(b)
```

… and then wrap it in a `BufferedWriter` and a `TextIOWrapper` and store the result as `sys.stdout`, and then do the same for `sys.stderr`. Then, the stdout of any thread is just `b''.join(ThreadedStdWriter.buffers[thread_id])`.