# Save output of four parallely running python program to different log files

Tags: python, linux, logging, multiprocessing, nohup

I have four different programs running which is started using a single python program.

```
import os                                                                       
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import sys   
processes = ('p1.py', 'p2.py', 'p3.py','p4.py')
def run_process(process):                                                             
    os.system('python3 {}'.format(process)) 
pool = Pool(processes=4)                                                        
pool.map(run_process, processes)
```

currently iam getting the log of all programs in a single file using nohup `pmain.py>test.log`
But how can i get four different logs of p1,p2,p3 and p4 respectively in different log files.

Comment: A simple fix would be to `processes = ('p1.py > p1.log', 'p2.py > p2.log', 'p3.py > p3.log', 'p4.py > p4.log')`. But don't do that. And don't do `os.system` as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log output of multiprocessing.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501651/log-output-of-multiprocessing-process)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-a-rotator-and-namer-to-customize-log-rotation-processing ,,, https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.QueueHandler

Comment: Or this?..[How should I log while using multiprocessing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641420/how-should-i-log-while-using-multiprocessing-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple fix will be to do,

```
import os                                                                       
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import sys   
processes = ('p1.py > p1.log', 'p2.py > p2.log', 'p3.py > p3.log','p4.py > p4.log')
def run_process(process):                                                             
    os.system('python3 {}'.format(process)) 
pool = Pool(processes=4)                                                        
pool.map(run_process, processes)
```

**But don't do the above.**

The right way to do that would be using `subprocess` with something like,

```
import subprocess
processes = ('p1.py', 'p2.py', 'p3.py','p4.py')
procs = []
for pname in processes:
  logfile = os.path.splitext(pname)[0] + '.log'
  with open(logfile, 'w') as f:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', pname], stdout=f)
    procs.append(proc)

for proc in procs:
  proc.wait()
```

Comment: why do you prefer the second way instead of the first method.

Comment: Because it is frowned upon to directly use `os.system`, and the second method is very readable, and does the same thing

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` is a non-blocking call. One would want to wait for all the processes to exit ?

Comment: No problem. I am glad, i was able to help